# Is the tensorflow inception-v3 model rotation invariant?

Tags: tensorflow

I retrained the inception-v3 model on my own classes and I am encountering a problem there:

When I predict the class of a specific image I get exactly the same result as when I rotate that image by 90 or 180 degree and predict the class of the rotated image.

So got confused and I am asking myself: **Is the tensorflow inception-v3 model rotation invariant?**

In my case the rotation of the object is important and an image x can be of class A but when x gets rotated it becomes and object of class B (For example when classifying digits: a by 180 degree rotated 6 becomes a 9).

Answer (score 1):

InceptionV3 is not rotationally invariant. Indeed, InceptionV3 contains of convolutional layers, which means that a small (say, 3x3) block is multiplied by a trained 3x3 set of weights. Those weights are *not* restricted to being rotationally invariant, so the network can and will produce different activations when the input is rotated.

That said, Inception is a fairly smart network, and if you feed it with (say) an image of a rotated dog, it should have no difficulty figuring out that this is still a dog (or at least, more similar to a dog than to any other class). You should notice though that the class probabilities change somewhat for the rotated image.

Comment: Actually, the probabillities do not change at all, they really stay the same. That's what's confusing me. Any Idea why that is? What can I do to differenciate between the rotated versions of the image?